# Deriving a specific motion equation for animation

Tags: math, animation, physics

I am in the process of prototyping a game and I have problem with derivation of a motion equation.

There is a ball that spawns on the screen with an initial velocity. It has a fixed target (fixed distance). There is fixed acceleration (deceleration in this case). So the ball slows down while reaching the destination.

I m trying to compute this:

What should the initial velocity (u) of the ball be, if I want its final velocity to be 25% of its initial velocity (u / 4) when it reaches (for the first time) to the target? The acceleration, distance and time are constants!

Ideally, I would want to have the ratio of the final velocity to the initial velocity a variable but I think I can find a way to make it work once I figure out how to derive the simple case.

To summarize:

```
Distance: Constant
Time: Constant
Acceleration: Constant
Initial velocity: u
Final velocity at destination: u / 4
```

How to solve for u? How can it be generalized for different final velocity ratios?

Thanks for any input or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem you're having is because you're overconstraining your system. From the variation of speed in time, `v = v0 + at`, using acceleration and time as constants, you have

```
u/4 = u + AT
-3/4*u = AT
u = -4/3*AT
```

But that may disagree with what you would find giving distance as a constant, from `v^2 = v0^2 + 2ad` ([Torricelli's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_equation))

```
(u/4)^2 - u^2 = 2AD
-15/16*u^2 = 2AD
u = sqrt(-32/15*AD)
```

In summary, you can't specify all three as constants. Of course, you can have what you want if you specify an acceleration variating with time (the variation of acceleration is called [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29)), but I'll let you derive the equations needed :)